# Issue styling Bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with styling buttons in Bootstrap and I hope you can help me.

I have tried this in JS fiddle and I have got it working they way I want it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26088/). So When I hover over the button I get dark Blue and when I click it I get the same dark Blue.

However when I view the page on Firefox or Chrome and I click the button the default color (Grey) for 'btn-default' class appears. I am a total beginner and from my short time learning CSS and Bootstrap, the active Pseudo-class is for when the button is clicked. I have tried override it using this:

```
.btn-default.active, .btn-default:active{
    background-color: #1e3c89;
    border-color: #1e3c89;
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Thank you for your responses. I am not sure I am explaining what I am trying to achieve correctly. So I have posted a link [here](http://imgur.com/tYE9PN4) that properly illustrates my problem (apologies for the quality). The current state of the button is light blue, when I hover it is dark blue. You notice the button then turns grey, that is when I click the button. When I click the button I want it to be the same dark blue.

Comment: So what you actually want ?

Comment: *:active* is for when its currently being clicked, means that it releases together with the mouse click. (When u let the mouse go) We need more code to find the exact problem.

Comment: What you want to do? Change the colour of the "active" state? If so, you do right already but need to change the colours to be different to hover & focus-state.

Comment: @HusainAhmmed I have updated my post with a video showing what my problem is and what I want to do.

Comment: Okay I saw your update. But without your code it's difficult for us to find out the issue you are facing. So please paste your code in your question so we can try to figure out what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the same colors for the hover and the active state.

Try to change the colors for the active state

```
.btn-default.active, .btn-default:active {
   background-color: #5e4c89;
   border-color: #5e4c89;
   color: #fff;
   box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rooo55nw/

Comment: Please see my updated post. It includes a gif and an explanation as to what I want to do.